# Off-Topic flag declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I was looking at my flag history today and saw one of my older flags(about 8 months old) got declined.

As stated in the comments of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972227/failed-trying-to-fill-a-list-with-buttons-in-tkinter) it was a simple error made by OP so I flagged it as off-topic - typo but it got declined.
So just to be sure for further flags, is it wrong to flag these type of problems as off topic typo? If yes what should've been done for it? Leave it as is?

Comment: **Flagging** would be wrong. *Voting to close* (if you have the privilege) has that as an option.

Comment: @paulie_d If you do not have sufficient reputation to vote to close, then you get an additional flag option for closing. It causes the post to enter close review, but does not count as a vote.

Comment: just keep up the good work with Python. You will be there shortly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flagging caused the post to enter the review queue, but the majority of reviewers did not vote to close, probably because the error is not immediately obvious. Review queues can be a bit of a crapshot.

You may be able to improve the chances by adding an explicit comment, such as "since the question was caused by the typo xy and has been resolved entirely by the comment made by yz, I propose to close this question."